# gridview Edit Row RegisterPostBackControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

After much searching and testing, it's time to ask for opinions.
A GridView inside an Update Panel with a file upload in an EditItemTemplate:

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
                        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
                        OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" >
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="true" >                                    
                            </asp:CommandField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attachment" SortExpression="FileName">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddAttachment" runat="server" Text="Upload File" CommandName="AddAttachment"
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ID") %>' />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <a id="ancLink" runat="server" href='<%# "~/Files/" + (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FileName")) %>'
                                        target="_blank">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblAnchor" runat="server"></asp:Label></a>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
         </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
 </asp:Content>
```

Then for the button in the EditItemTemplate, add the RegisterPostBackControl:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit) || ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0))
            {
                Button btnAddAttachment = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnAddAttachment");
                AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager ToolkitScriptManager1 = (AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager)Master.FindControl("ToolkitScriptManager1");
                ToolkitScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(btnAddAttachment);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the RegisterPostBackControl will not work the first time an attempt is made to upload a file. If a user edits the same row again, the second attempt works fine.
Most likely because the RegisterPostBackControl takes effect on the second post back.
Is there a way to have the button have a full postback the first time?
I know there is an easy way for a work around but this defeats the purpose of the UpdatePanel:

```
     <Triggers>
         <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="GridView1" />
     </Triggers>
```

And since only Admins will have access to editing, setting the PostBackTrigger for the grid in the code behind for only admins is also an option, but once again, defeating the purpose of the Update Panel.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `RowDataBound` is only triggered if you bind the `DataSource` to the `GridView` but imo you need to call `RegisterPostBackControl` on every postback. Therefore use `RowCreated` instead.

Comment: This way, we have to bind many controls as trigger. That'll be so ugly. I suggest you set `OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"` event of gridview. Meanwhile, please set the `commandname` to the button(`CommandName="upload"`). Then you just need set the GridView Command event as the trigger. In addition, you can do something in rowcommand event on server-side, and you'll know which fileupload control trigger the postback.

Comment: @Tim - Adding it to the RowCreated event does not work.@Avijit - Adding it to the RowCommand does not work. But thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on lots of factors, you could try the updatepannel option:

```
ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
```

It may work as a temporary workaround if you need to push something out now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you have the `UpdatePanel` using the default values so `ChildrenAsTriggers` is true and `UpdateMode` is Always, so you should get a full postback every time.

But I don't see you setting the Gridview's DataSourceID so it won't Databind unless you do so somewhere in the code behind.  But you would have to be in edit mode initially in order to even find the control you're trying to register.  So you need to register the control when you go into edit mode, try finding and registering the control in the gridview RowEditing event

Comment: The grid is bound in the code behind. I never use sqldatasource - ever. The button is found in the RowEditing event but adding the RegisterPostbackControl there still does not work.